# NiFi: Modify flow without disruption or downtime using Java API

Tags: apache-nifi

Is there a way to modify NiFi flow dynamically using Java API? The use case is to add a processor to an active data flow (data is flowing through it). The new processor should be added at the beginning of the flow without application disruption or downtime.

In case Java API is not available, please feel free to suggest alternatives. I have already looked at [change-nifi-flow-using-rest-api-part-1](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/87217/change-nifi-flow-using-rest-api-part-1.html). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Any action you can perform from the UI can also be performed from REST API, the UI is just making calls to the REST API behind the scenes.

I would suggest opening Chrome's Dev Tools and performing the action you are interested in and then seeing what requests were made to perform the action. You can then script these operations however you need.

In addition, if you are trying to deploy flows then you should be taking advantage of NiFi Registry which allows you to place a flow under version control. You can then make changes from your local instance or dev instance, and upgrade the flow in production in-place without stopping your whole NiFi instance.